# How to get rid of: Warning: Cannot find any files matching pattern "dotenv_config_path=.env.test"

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, dotenv, ts-node

I'm currently working on a NodeJS project that uses TypeScript, and I'm currently trying to test my application using Mocha. The main issue I am having is that I am getting a warning when I am trying to get Mocha to load the dotenv module in the Terminal and have the .env path be configured to: .env.test

This is the command I used:

`mocha -r ts-node/register -r dotenv/config 'tests/**/*.ts' dotenv_config_path=.env.test`

When executing this command, Mocha gives me the following warning:

`Warning: Cannot find any files matching pattern "dotenv_config_path=.env.test"`

But afterwards, it successfully loads the dotenv module with the .env.test path, and it's able to go through all my test cases without any errors.

Is there any way to get rid of this warning? Or what is the preferred setup so that I wouldn't get this warning to begin with?

Comment: You're missing `--`

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you! That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) had pointed out, it turns out that I forgot the `--` before configuring my `dotenv_config_path`.

The complete command now is:

`mocha -r ts-node/register -r dotenv/config 'tests/**/*.ts' --dotenv_config_path=.env.test`

Comment: This was giving me the same warning as before. Per [dotenv docs](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#preload) you can also use env vars to set a custom .env path. This should do it: `DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=.env.test mocha -r ts-node/register -r dotenv/config 'tests/**/*.ts'`